# EF core creates delay after the DB access

Tags: c#, wpf, debugging, entity-framework-core

I have a WPF application where a DB view is displayed in a `DataGrid`. I implemented paging. When I go to the next page, I query the DB and refresh the `ObservableCollection` in the View Model. The latter takes about 2s (without the query). The view is only notified once with the help of a custom `ObservableCollection`.

If instead of a DB query I create test data then the refresh needs only 0.2s. I want to reach this refresh time with the real data.

I tried `AsNoTracking` with the query but it did not help. I tried to convert the EF proxy classes to poco classes but no result. **Then I realized if I query the DB but I do not use the result but the test data then the refresh is still 2s.** This is strange. May be the EF call creates some mess and that is why subsequent instructions are slower. `GC.Collect();` did not help.

```
dbViewItems = await DbViewSelectorOld(dbContext).FromSql(dbScript).AsNoTracking()
    .Where(WhereCondition).OrderBy(OrderByCondition)
    .Skip(numberOfRowsToBeSkipped).Take(numberOfRowsToBeTaken)
    .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

var stopWatch = new Stopwatch(); // start of the refresh
stopWatch.Start();
var displayClassItems = dbViewItems.Select(FromViewClassCreateDisplayClass).ToList();
DisplayedRows.ClearWithSingleNotification();
DisplayedRows.AddRangeWithSingleNotification(displayClassItems);
DisplayedRowsBackup.Clear();
DisplayedRowsBackup.AddTheCopy(displayClassItems);
Console.WriteLine(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

`DisplayedRows` is the `ItemsSource` and I have a backup as well. Any idea?

Comment: `ConfigureAwait(false)` seem very odd in a UI program, you would presumably *want* to continue on the original synchronization context. So check that you are actually on the UI thread when updating the UI. If that is not the case I would expect your code to just crash, but just being slower is not outside the realm of possibilities.

Comment: @JonasH Thank you, your suggestion worked. I misunderstood `ConfigureAwait(false)`. I thought it means we can resume on any thread that is available. So the true is more restrictive but it is better in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConfigureAwait(false)` allows the code after the await run from the thread pool instead of the UI thread [*]. This can be used to improve performance and avoid unneeded synchronization.

But in UI programs this synchronization is *important*. We are only allowed to modify UI objects from the UI from the UI thread, so we *want* the runtime to synchronize execution back to the UI thread, so we can use the results to update the UI.

In general I would recommend just not using `ConfigureAwait(false)` unless you have a specific reason to do so. I.e. If you are unsure, use the default. From the [ConfigureAwait FAQ](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/)

> **When should I use ConfigureAwait(false)?**
>
> It depends: are you implementing application-level code or general-purpose library code?
>
> When writing applications, you generally want the default behavior (which is why it is the default behavior). If an app model / environment (e.g. Windows Forms, WPF, ASP.NET Core, etc.) publishes a custom SynchronizationContext, there’s almost certainly a really good reason it does: it’s providing a way for code that cares about synchronization context to interact with the app model / environment appropriately. So if you’re writing an event handler in a Windows Forms app, writing a unit test in xunit, writing code in an ASP.NET MVC controller, whether or not the app model did in fact publish a SynchronizationContext, you want to use that SynchronizationContext if it exists. And that means the default / ConfigureAwait(true). You make simple use of await, and the right things happen with regards to callbacks/continuations being posted back to the original context if one existed. This leads to the general guidance of: **if you’re writing app-level code, do not use ConfigureAwait(false)**

[*] The framework models this as "Synchronization contexts", and this is a fairly general concept. But for most desktop applications this will break down into either The UI thread, or an arbitrary thread pool thread. The link provides a much more comprehensive description that I could hope to make.